# Laravel custom routing files not working with new routes

Tags: api, single-page-application, laravel-8, vuejs3

I am building a CMS SPA with Laravel 8 and I wanted to seperate the routes by category (admin, api, auth) in seperate route files with the use of custom slugs (/admin/settings , /auth/login) but I cant seem to get it to work so what am I doing wrong? It all did work when it was the API file but when dividing it over seprate files it wont work.

**routes/admin.php**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::get('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('settings');
});
```

**routeServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::prefix('auth')
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/auth.php'));

        Route::prefix('admin')
            ->middleware('admin')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));

    });
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
   return view('layouts.vue');
})->where('any', '^(?!api|admin|auth).*$');
```

**kernel.php**

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
    'auth' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ]
];
```

**Component.vue**

```php
const response = axios.get('/admin/settings')// not giving the data back
const response = axios.get('/api/settings')// in the past did work
```

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` output?

Answer (score 0):

While someone else gives a better answer about your approach. As simple way to achieve `/admin/settings` in the web/routes.php file would be to use prefixes

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function() {
  Route::get('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'index']);
});
```

With this approach you won't need to make changes to your `app\Http\kernel.php` or `routeServiceProvider.php` files.

Also if you want to abstract it away, you could put your it in a new file and just require `require_once __DIR__ . '/admin.php';` as you would a regular php file.